# How to distinguish between staging and live on a JSP portlet?

Tags: java, jsp, liferay, portlet

I’m beginning to make a JSP form portlet and I have 2 doubts.

1)
I’ve made a structure and the respective template, and created several web contents with this.
Now I’m creating a JSP portlet to display the web contents, I’m getting all the contents with the `JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.getStructureArticles()`, but whenever I add more content, it automatically appears in Live and Staging instead of only appearing in staging.
How can I fix this?

2)
Does Liferay sanitizes all the inputs automatically to prevent SQL injections and XSS attacks?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

1) if you're always using the same `groupId`, you'll always get the same content: The Live and Staging Sites have different group Ids. You'll typically use the "current" groupId, which means the staging one when in staging and the live one when in live.

2) Servicebuilder typically is safe from SQL-injections unless you construct your SQL queries manually. As there are some legitimate uses of scripting content, you'll have to determine the level of escaping user-generated content for yourself, Liferay provides the class `HtmlUtil` with various escaping methods. Pick the ones you need. For general use, e.g. to sanitize WebContent, Blogs etc., you might want to deploy the AntiSamy plugin from Liferay's Marketplace

Comment: i)
you are correct, liferay figures what is correct groupId, but i also have to pass the structure ID.
Now i'm giving the portlet the staging id of the structure, how can i get the live id?
2)
Thank you

Comment: Use the structure UUID instead of its structureId: UUIDs don't change between staging and live environments.

Comment: This is true for structures but not for content. Do you now how get the live content id from the content staging id?